# How to Send SOAP Request to a Web Service in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angular, web-services, ionic-framework, soap

I am completely new in Ionic as well as Web Development, However i am learning to Develop an App through Ionic Framework. I want to send a SOAP Request through my application, I checked many threads about Sending SOAP Request through Angular and the one i tried to implement is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296983/soap-wsdl-request-angular2-4-framework), But, this doesn't seem to work for me, I didn't get a reponse from the server. The status shows 0. I followed exact steps mentioned there. Help would be really Appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not about Angular/ Ionic. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example, you should make it through.

Comment: Still no success. I am not getting any response.

Comment: I am getting a 400 Bad Request Error.

Comment: Is the API you are calling public? If so, I can have a try. If not, you need to figure it out the reason, definitely that should be your HTTP request issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it is only local. Shall i post my code? so that you could check if my request is correct. Because the same request is working on soap Ui but here i get a 400 Bad request error. I have added all the necessary headers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the error. I was getting this error :-

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access."

Solved it by typing this command in Run, **chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security**

Opening my ionic app in this new instance of chrome gave me the reponse from the server